# 2004 Saab 9-5 2.3t is stalling when the A/C is on... what could it be?

Tags: ac, stall, saab, compressor

2004 Saab 9-5 2.3t is stalling when the A/C is on... what could it be? My mechanic added Freon and it was working ok but now it seems like the engine wants to give up. Could it be the compressor?

Comment: The idle control valve may not be working.